# Failed to compile src\Search.js: setEndDate, selectionRange and handSelect are not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, compiler-errors, daterangepicker

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import './search.css'
import "react-date-range/dist/styles.css";
import "react-date-range/dist/theme/default.css"
import {DateRangePicker} from "react-date-range";

function Search() {
   const[startDate,setStartDate]=useState(new Date());
   const[endDate,setendDate]=useState(new Date());

const selctionRange = {
    startdate:startDate,
    endDate:endDate,
    key:"selection",
}

function handleSelect(ranges){
    setStartDate(ranges.seection.startDate);
    setEndDate(ranges.selection.endDate);
}
return (
    <div className="search">
        <DateRangePicker ranges={
            [selectionRange]} onChange={handSelect}/>
         
    </div>
)
}

export default Search
```

---

### the above is the code and this is the error

Failed to compile
src\Search.js
Line 19:9:   'setEndDate' is not defined      no-undef
Line 24:18:  'selectionRange' is not defined  no-undef
Line 24:45:  'handSelect' is not defined      no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `setEndDate` but you defined `setendDate` in your useState (without the major E).

Edit: Same thing for `selectionRange`, you defined `selctionRange` and `handSelect` with `handleSelect`. Only typos.

Comment: Really thanks highly appreciated brother i will surly try to improve my typos i just write the code in hurry and then searches for the error 

thanks again